# I'm trying to import a fbx file into blender but it doesnt show up, even in objects list

Tags: import

I dont see any messages from blender, I just try to import the file and when I click the import button nothing happens except the file select thing goes away

Comment: Can you view the fbx in any other software?
Maybe in MeshLab?
Maybe your `.fbx` is corrupted. If so, maybe Meshlab can fix it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.